# Using BLE function in a fragment instead of MainActivity

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to build an app which scans for BLE devices in one of it's fragment. i am using viewpager to move between tabs. in one of the fragment i want to use BLE scan function. however due to the class belonging to Fragment i can't use some of the function necessary for my code. can anyone tell me how to solve it. how can i use the code in fragment and call it in the viewpager. there is also a refresh button which should refresh the list,

```
class Bluetooth : Fragment() {

        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bluetooth, container, false)
        }

        private fun isLocationPermissionEnabled(): Boolean {
            return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(**this**, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        }

        private val bleScanner = object : ScanCallback() {
            override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
                super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)
                Log.d("DeviceListActivity", "onScanResult: ${result?.device?.address} - ${result?.device?.name}")
            }

            override fun onBatchScanResults(results: MutableList<ScanResult>?) {
                super.onBatchScanResults(results)
                Log.d("DeviceListActivity", "onBatchScanResults:${results.toString()}")
            }

            override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
                super.onScanFailed(errorCode)
                Log.d("DeviceListActivity", "onScanFailed: $errorCode")
            }

        }

        private val bluetoothLeScanner: BluetoothLeScanner
            get() {
                val bluetoothManager = **applicationContext**.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
                val bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
                return bluetoothAdapter.bluetoothLeScanner
            }

        class ListDevicesAdapter(context: Context, resource: Int) : ArrayAdapter<String>(context, resource)

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            Log.d("DeviceListActivity", "onCreate()")
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            **setContentView**(R.layout.fragment_bluetooth)
        }

        override fun onStart() {
            Log.d("DeviceListActivity", "onStart()")
            super.onStart()

            bluetoothLeScanner.startScan(bleScanner)

        }

        override fun onStop() {
            bluetoothLeScanner.stopScan(bleScanner)
            super.onStop()
        }
    }
```

the errors i am getting is (this,....), setcontentview and (applicationcontext. ...) and marked in Bold format in the code here.

this is my main activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val adapter = MyViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
    adapter.addFragment(Bluetooth(), "Devices")
    adapter.addFragment(Information(), "Information")
    adapter.addFragment(Log(), "Log")
    viewpager.adapter = adapter
    tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewpager)
    refresh.setOnClickListener { Bluetooth() }

}


class MyViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager) {

    private val fragmentlist: MutableList<Fragment> = ArrayList()
    private val titlelist: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragmentlist[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return fragmentlist.size
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return titlelist[position]
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
        fragmentlist.add(fragment)
        titlelist.add(title)
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, BLE have nothing to with your error. Your post is misleading.

Comment: That's not how StackOverflow works, you should be continuing your original question instead of posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

1.
You can directly use the **activity** or **context** reference in your fragment.

So instead of using **this** and **applicationContext** use `getActivity()` ot `getContext()` method.

2.
remove the `setContentView()` from on create as its of no need cause you are already inflating the view properly in `onCreateView()`.